# Need a trigger to prevent Unique input update from a table window

Tags: mysql

I have a frontend application with a windows table for insert/update/delete rows in a database table. I have one unique column and I'm looking for a trigger to prevent and give a meaninful error to the user when trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: why not just put a unique constraint on the field?

Answer (score 0):

create a unique constraint in that column. If user tries to enter a value which is already present in that table you will get `MySql error 1062 "Duplicate entry...."`, at that time show user "Value you entered already exist, please enter a different value"